# Can W gate be written only using H,T?

Tags: quantum-gate, universal-gates, transpile

I want to write the decompose the gate $W=(X+Y)/\sqrt{2}$ using only $H$ and $T$ (and all the derived Clifford gates basically). I know $H=(X+Z)/\sqrt{2}$ is it possible to obtain exactly $W$ from this set (no approximation)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the sequence:
$$
HT^6HT^2H.
$$
What was my thinking? I'm used to doing a transformation that looks something like
$$
S^\dagger H S.
$$
The action is the $S$ is to preserve the $Z$ term inside $H$, but transforms the $X$ term into a $Y$. So, we take the $S=T^2$ and $S^\dagger=T^6$, and this gives
$$
T^6HT^2=(Z-Y)/\sqrt{2}.
$$
Now, conjugate with Hadamards to change $Z\mapsto X$ and $Y\mapsto -Y$.

Comment: Thanks that works!